# Jquery with bootstrap 4

Tags: jquery, web, bootstrap-4

When I run these code while using bootstrap the following error appears

> practice.js:11 Uncaught TypeError: $(...).fadeOut is not a function

My Code :-

HTML :

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>

  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1, shrink-to-fit=no">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.3.1/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-ggOyR0iXCbMQv3Xipma34MD+dH/1fQ784/j6cY/iJTQUOhcWr7x9JvoRxT2MZw1T" crossorigin="anonymous">
  <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Roboto+Condensed&display=swap" rel="stylesheet">

  <link rel="stylesheet" href="practice.css">
  <script type="text/javascript" src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-2.1.4.js"></script>

  <title></title>

</head>

<body>


  <div id="effect" class="row my-5">
    <div class="col-3"></div>
    <div class="col-6">
      <img class="img-fluid" src="https://scontent.fjrs1-1.fna.fbcdn.net/v/t1.15752-9/107376723_279529570050364_381202387595922170_n.jpg?_nc_cat=100&_nc_sid=b96e70&_nc_ohc=zXTVBn-CzdsAX_OnKdo&_nc_ht=scontent.fjrs1-1.fna&oh=68eafa443772a6c0d0e773c1d6f794c4&oe=5F2853BC"
        alt="">
    </div>
    <div class="col-3"></div>
  </div>


  <script src="practice.js"></script>

  <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.2.1.slim.min.js" integrity="sha384-KJ3o2DKtIkvYIK3UENzmM7KCkRr/rE9/Qpg6aAZGJwFDMVNA/GpGFF93hXpG5KkN" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
  <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/popper.js/1.12.9/umd/popper.min.js" integrity="sha384-ApNbgh9B+Y1QKtv3Rn7W3mgPxhU9K/ScQsAP7hUibX39j7fakFPskvXusvfa0b4Q" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
  <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-JZR6Spejh4U02d8jOt6vLEHfe/JQGiRRSQQxSfFWpi1MquVdAyjUar5+76PVCmYl" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
</body>

</html>
```

JavaScript :

```
$("#effect").on("click", function() {
    $(this).fadeOut();
});
```

Answer (score 0):

You are loading jQuery twice.

First, you load `jquery-2.1.4.js` (which is obsolete, has known security issues, and should not be used).

Then you load `jquery-3.2.1.slim.min.js` (which is obsolete, etc, etc, **and** doesn't include the effects module that you are trying to use!).

---

Load jQuery **only once**, make it the **current** version (3.5.1) and **don't** use the slim version if you need features it doesn't include.

Answer (score 0):

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<html>

<head>

  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1, shrink-to-fit=no">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.3.1/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-ggOyR0iXCbMQv3Xipma34MD+dH/1fQ784/j6cY/iJTQUOhcWr7x9JvoRxT2MZw1T" crossorigin="anonymous">
  <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Roboto+Condensed&display=swap" rel="stylesheet">

  <link rel="stylesheet" href="practice.css">
  <title></title>

</head>

<body>


  <div id="effect" class="row my-5">
    <div class="col-3"></div>
    <div class="col-6">
      <img class="img-fluid" src="https://scontent.fjrs1-1.fna.fbcdn.net/v/t1.15752-9/107376723_279529570050364_381202387595922170_n.jpg?_nc_cat=100&_nc_sid=b96e70&_nc_ohc=zXTVBn-CzdsAX_OnKdo&_nc_ht=scontent.fjrs1-1.fna&oh=68eafa443772a6c0d0e773c1d6f794c4&oe=5F2853BC"
        alt="">
    </div>
    <div class="col-3"></div>
  </div>
  
  <button class="btn1">Fade out</button>
  <button class="btn2">Fade in</button>


  <script src="practice.js"></script>
  
  <script>
   $(".btn1").click(function(){
    $("img").fadeOut();
  });
  $(".btn2").click(function(){
    $("img").fadeIn();
  });
  </script>
  <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/popper.js/1.12.9/umd/popper.min.js" integrity="sha384-ApNbgh9B+Y1QKtv3Rn7W3mgPxhU9K/ScQsAP7hUibX39j7fakFPskvXusvfa0b4Q" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
  <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-JZR6Spejh4U02d8jOt6vLEHfe/JQGiRRSQQxSfFWpi1MquVdAyjUar5+76PVCmYl" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
</body>

</html>
```

you can do somthing like this.jquery in your code is not defined correctly as from the error